# What is Canadian Sphagnum Peat Moss and is it any Sphagnum sourced from Canada?

Tags: blueberries, peat

I'm working on the right composition of planting mix for blueberries in a high pH environment. In addition to a regimen of ammonium sulphate + sulphur I'm thinking to start with a soil, sphagnum peat moss and pine bark mix. But I need to be sure I get the right kind of "peat moss."

[Iowa State](https://hortnews.extension.iastate.edu/how-change-your-soils-ph) makes the following statement:

> However, most peat moss found in garden centers is neutral or slightly
> acidic.  Only Canadian sphagnum peat moss has a low pH of 3.0 to 4.5
> and will effectively reduce soil pH.

This raises a warning flag, to be sure I'm getting the right product.

My local hardware (Menards) carries Premier brand "`Sphagnum Peat Moss [Tourbe de sphaigne]`" which does not use the word "`Canadian`" but is labelled at the bottom as a "`Product of Canada`." But Menards also sells a much more expensive "`Peat Moss Canadian Sphagnum`" by Schultz which *does* use the adjective "`Canadian`." Are these the same thing (e.g. both 3.0 - 4.5 pH)?

Does the fact that the Premier product comes from Canada mean it's this lower pH product Iowa State is referring to? I ask because I don't recall ever seeing any other kind of peat moss in  hardware stores, so wondering what the "`*most* peat moss found in garden centers`" is actually referring to. I want to make sure I don't buy a higher-pH product at the bulk I need.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up buying a single unit of both these products and several other peat moss products from various stores, and pH testing them (at home, not professionally). Here are my results:

```
Miracle Gro Sphagnum Peat Moss - ph 5.0
Greensmix Sphagnum Peat Moss - ph 5.0
Premier Sphagnum Peat Moss - ph 5.5
Schultz Peat Moss Canadian Sphagnum - ph 8.5!!!
```

I double tested them all, so while my numbers may be off due to color matching, they are definitely meaningful side-by-side. Clearly, Schultz' product is strongly alkaline and would be a sad surprise to anybody adding it to their blueberries!